# using two server for image and web app and synchronization between them

Tags: web-server, hosting, web-hosting

I am using a cloud space for running my web apps with limited storage. My web app provides user to upload and share unlimited data,images & videos.

Is there other cloud file storage facility which provides unlimited images video uploading.

And is it possible that I run my web app with existing cloud and when ever user upload images,videos it should store on other cloud.
If possible then how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use an OAUTH authentication approach that includes access to the auth hosts storage. For example you authenticate your users using Google OAUTH and obtain permission to store the assets in their cloud drive storage. Not exactly unlimited however asking for a hosting service that you can sync to that provides unlimited media storage does seem like a big ask.

Are you looking to be able to pull the assets back and serve them through your limited storage hosted app?

You don't specify that you require the media storage to be free so you could use Google/Amazon etc storage services.

Comment: Mainly I want to store Images and videos unlimited.

Comment: so perhaps you could use google auth and bind to the users YouTube/Picassa storage or something along those lines .. there may be better approaches will be interesting to see if there's a better approach.

Comment: No. Users will only upload their images/videos to my site(On my rent space) I want to store image at any space(Privately) I dont want to bind it with users other google service. My  sites data should not be shared/accessed through any service except ony mine

Comment: perhaps something from one of these? http://www.thetop10bestonlinebackup.com/cloud-storage am guesing that you are looking for comparison advice .. start with https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing and look at amazon .. model your requirements based on your own pricing and anticipated user usage.

Comment: Tes I have seen this .